# Variadic templates mystery

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Here is the code that works fine :

```
template<typename... Args> struct count;

template<>
struct count<> {
static const int value = 0;
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct count<T, Args...> {
static const int value = 1 + count<Args...>::value;
};
```

**now i was wondering why we need to partial specialize the count class template?**

Can we do something like :

```
template< typename... args> struct dd; // edited according to answer but now getting error redeclared with 2 template parameters which is point below with mark %%

template<>
struct dd<>{
static const int value = 0;
};

template<typename T, typename... args> //%%
struct dd{
static const int value= 1+ dd<args...>::value;
};
```

**but this doesn't works but why?**

Any help is very appreciated :)

**Edit** : edited the solution according to answer.

Comment: Note that you can do `sizeof(args)` to get the count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `template <typename T, typename... Args>` you can't create a specialisation that omits `T` (i.e. `dd<>`) — the pack can be empty, but `T` can't. So you declare the template as one that takes only a pack, specialise for empty pack to stop recursion, and partially specialise for `<T, Args...>` to unpack one type and create a new pack with (n - 1) types.

As for the edit: you can't define another template with different arguments but the same name, you have to specialise the already existing one.

Answer (score 5):

```
template<>
struct dd<> {
static const int value = 0;
};
```

is not a specialization of

```
template< typename T,typename... args> struct dd;
```

which says `dd` will always require at least one parameter.

---

Sidenote, there already is a built-in way to get the number of variadic template parameters and the `count` struct could be implemented as

```
template <class ...args>
struct count
{
    static const int value = sizeof...(args);
};
```

Comment: so if do some thing like `template<typename... args> struct dd;` as primary template in second code it should work?. I am still unable to understand your answer, re-edit it please?. Thanks

Comment: @Mr.Anubis Yes, then it would work (being the same as your first snippet).